# How to change save directory of w3m cookie files to another directory

Tags: emacs

I want to manage emacs config files in public github, so I need to separate config files and my personal data.

It seems `w3m` save cookies in `~/.emacs.d` directory.
I couldn't find the config to change the place to saving.
How can I change the directory?